# How to get a full PowerShell version as a single-line string?

Tags: powershell, version

At first glance you may be tempted to dismiss this question as something that can be easily searched, but please bear with me and read on.

I know that there are multiple ways to find the PowerShell version, but I specifically need a clean single line output without any fancy tables or new lines, that I can put into a variable.

`(Get-Host).Version` gives me:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  2673
```

`Get-Host | Select-Object Version` gives me:

```
Version
-------
5.1.19041.2673
```

`Get-Host | Format-List -Property Version` gives me:

```
Version : 5.1.19041.2673
```

*(with two new lines above and below)*

`Get-Host | Format-Wide -Property Version` gives me the closest thing to my desire:

```
5.1.19041.2673
```

*(with two new lines above and below)*

Basically, I am looking for **the simplest way** to just get `5.1.19041.2673` in the output without any additional columns, new lines or descriptions.

Comment: `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you @SantiagoSquarzon, that certainly achieves what I'm looking for, but there is one caveat. $PSVersionTable does not work in PowerShell version 1, I think it was introduced in version 2, which is why I went with Get-Host. Can you think of a way to do the same with Get-Host?

Comment: The key was the `.ToString()` call. You can still call it over `.Version`

Comment: Ah, I tried it with Get-Host | Format-Wide -Property Version.ToString(), which didn't work, but (Get-Host).Version.ToString() seems to work. Thanks. If you can put this as an answer, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [`.ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-version-tostring) on the `.Version` property to get the output you're looking for:

```
(Get-Host).Version.ToString()
```

Coercing to a string would also work:

```
[string] (Get-Host).Version
```